# JSON: Concatenate 2 string values in value

Tags: android, python, json

Hi I have a JSON like:

```
{
"name" : "avg",
"code" : {"value":" import android 
                    droid = android.Android() 
                    droid.makeToast('Hello, Android!')",
    "type":"PythonScript"
    } 
}
```

However, in value field(Python script for Android) I need a newline character between the 3 statements. Something like,

```
"value":"import android "  + "\n" + "droid = android.Android()" + "\n" + "droid.makeToast('Hello, Android!')"
```

Is it possible to do this? Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I am getting JSON Exception in eclipse when I try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its better to configure your server to send you **HTML-encoded** value string. Afterwards, it would be easier to re-construct and show in `TextView`, for e.g.

Your expected Json response:

```
{
    "name": "avg",
    "code": {
        "value": "import android<br />droid = android.Android()<br />droid.makeToast('Hello, Android!')",
        "type": "PythonScript"
    }
}
```

Once you read the *value* string:

```
String html_encoded_string = "import android<br />droid = android.Android()
<br />droid.makeToast('Hello, Android!')";
```

Then its easier to put it in *TextView* using html encoding:

```
yourTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(html_encoded_string));
```

Comment: Can u pls explain ur comment? @Waqas

Comment: see my answer. its updated. you just need to tweak your server a little to send you value in html response