# special character in JSON \n and double quote

Tags: java, json

I am having problem when convert string to json object.

`\n` gives out `Unterminated string` . If I want to use new line I use \n character, then it occurs the error.  Example String: Hello \n this is testing message.

double quote " gives out `Expected a ',' or '}` Exception. Example String : This is a "TESTING" message.

I use to escape \ to escape those , but still facing the JSON Exception

Comment: Can you refer to the answer in this link? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423234/json-concatenate-2-string-values-in-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use the StringEscapeUtils.escapeJavaScript() function which make my life easy.
http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html

Answer (score 0):

The \n, intended as "newline", must be encoded as \n in json.
\" is for quoting.

You can open the python shell, write

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps('\n"')
```

and see the result yourself

Comment: you have answered only one part. any idea for double quote?